# os.getcwd() to variable

Tags: python

This must be pretty basic, but I don't get this to work.

```
#!/project/x/software/bin/python
import os
import sys

print os.getcwd()
```

How do I save the os.getcwd() result to a variable, so I can modify the output etc.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `#!/project/x/software/bin/python` at all. If you move ore remove that bin folder, your scripts are all broken.

Comment: Please offer a solution also then.
Use:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
```

Strongly recommend going through: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/